# Email notification on customer response to case comment

Tags: case, customer-portal, email2case, servicecloud, case-object

I want to send an email to the Case Owner if a Customer responds to a case comment via email.
Is there any out of the box setting? Or do I need to write a trigger?

Comment: trigger should definitely NOT be required.  If the case comment went out with the threadId, then the response will come in as an `EmailMessage` and workflows can be written on `EmailMessage`

Comment: When I do that it doesn't show Email Send as one of the workflow actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's an approach

1. Create a workflow or Process Builder flow on `EmailMessage`
2. The workflow has a single action to do a field update on `Case`. Have the update be to set a custom checkbox field `Case.HasNewEmailMessage__c` to true.
3. Create a new workflow on Case that executes when `Case.HasNewEmailMessage__c` is TRUE.
4. This Case workflow sends an Email Alert to the Case Owner.  The same Case workfow does a field update to set `Case.HasNewEmailMessage__c` to false.